# How to configure sound for a service not connected to a logged in user account

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I am trying to configure a service (shairport-sync) that runs in the background on a system that also has multiple GUI user accounts that may or may not be logged in at any time. The system has one pair of speakers connected to it, which should play sounds from shairport-sync as well as the currently logged in user's account (if any). My goal is to have the volume control for shairport-sync be independent of the currently logged in user's volume controls. Currently the system works perfectly for logged in users, and I do not want to change that if possible. How would I configure Ubuntu to do this?

---

My understanding is that Ubuntu uses Pulse Audio and Alsa for sound, but I don't have a good grasp of how they are connected. It seems like Alsa is a lower-level service that Pulse connects to. However when I try to setup shairport-sync to use Alsa I get no sound, regardless of which output device (sink?) I choose, and mostly get errors like

```
failed to find mixer control "PCM".
the alsa output_device "hw:1" can not be found.
```

I think what I want to do is add a new "sink" (is that the right term?) to Alsa, which will take sound from shairport-sync and send it to the sound card. The GUI login session will use a different sink (and/or Pulse Audio?). Maybe I need two new sinks and a mixer? I've used Alsa for something like this in the past, but it was on a headless system with no user accounts (and no Pulse Audio) sharing the sound outputs.